# duplicate column and insert in new filed

Tags: sql, syntax, sybase

I have this record.

```
columnA columnB  
00001   1234  
00001   12345
```

I want to make it   how can I do this result?

```
columnA columnB columnC  
00001   1234    12345
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Do the columns have dynamic? if the columnA has five record for columnB then do the output should be six columns in total?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select top 1 columnA, columnB, LEAD(columnB) over (order by columnB)  as columnC from myTable
```